# Exporting JSON data type column in Source Azure postgres to destination CSV file in Azure data factory

Tags: postgresql, azure, etl

We have Azure Postgres Database as source and Azure Data lake as destination where we are having files in CSV format.
In one of the source table we have data type as JSON which after exporting to CSV file in ADL is getting split in multiple columns because of commas in JSON data.
Is there way if we can enclose entire JSON data in single column in CSV?

Thanks

Comment: Hi - please could you provide more details about what exactly you are doing. What ETL tool/process are you using to extract data from Postgres? What database structures are you loading into in ADL and how are you moving the data?

Comment: Can you provide any sample JSON data that you have in source table?